# Not override properties child constructors

Tags: php

How do I not override properties declared in parent classes in a child class with a constructor [php].

Ex:

```
class A {
    public $user;
    public function __construct {
        $this->user = 5;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public function __construct {
        //How do I make sure that the variables from the parent object are inherited?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override the parent's constructor

```
parent::__construct(); //add this in the child's construct() function
```

The `__construct()` syntax for both parent and child class  needs parentheses

```
public function __construct() {


}
```